# C# transparent label, how to inherit backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox with an image and a transparant label placed on top of it.

[image: picturebox with label]

The backcolor of the label is ARGB=(0, 255, 255, 255) which is transparent.

how can i get the color behind the label? e.g. RGB=(255,0,0)

Comment: No, the label is tranparant. I used the following code: mylabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent; 
mylabel.Parent = picturebox;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if fully understand your question. but if you need a color of image where the label is located then you may try out this-

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
 Color colorAtPoint = bitmap.GetPixel(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y);
```

Comment: Very good. Is it possible to get the average RGB value from the whole label background and not just 1 pixel?